# Program for checking gaps in hierarchy?

Tags: java

In my data I have few hierarchy values - example address

> Name -> Street -> City -> County -> State -> Country

The validation I need is: if a value in the above hierarchy is present, then all the previous/higher order values should be present.

Below is a valid case

> Name -> Street -> City -> State
> This is valid even though there is no country - as it is last in the order

and below is an invalid case

> Name -> Street -> State -> Country
> This is invalid as there is no City Which is of higher order than state and country.

The below code helped me in doing the checks. Can this be simplified further? I want to get rid of the last dummy return statement. (To the best of my knowledge, it is difficult to get rid of it. But there are more people far more knowledgeable than me.)

```
 package com.example.demo;

public class SimplyfyHierarchyCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a="a", b="b", c="c", d="d"; 

        SimplyfyHierarchyCheck shc = new SimplyfyHierarchyCheck();
        System.out.println(shc.isGapLessHierarchy("a", b, "", "") );
    }

    //can this method be made even more concise.
    private boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... args) { //Hierarchy 
        boolean isGapLess=true;

        for(int i=args.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(args[i].isBlank() )  //nothing to check 
            {
                continue;
            }
            for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
                if(args[j].isBlank() )  //gap found i.e false 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return isGapLess; //dummy return // am required to return true or false // can i get rid of this
    }

}
```

Comment: Why was this tagged C/C++? It's java.

Comment: IMO, you should always return `isGapLess`. In your loop, you can set `isGapLess  = false; break;` and then let the control to reach the last return statement

Comment: Is `County` excluded as _optional_ node in your hierarchical validation (first valid example without 'country')?

Comment: What is abstraction and what is true domain-context? What purpose has the gap-identification (i.e. to avoid "gaps in hierarchy"): an address should be _resolvable_ or be _specific enough_ to be locatable❔

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are looking for a more concise way, you can use a `for-loop` with an empty body:

```
boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... args) {
    int i = args.length - 1;
    for (; i >= 0 && args[i].isBlank(); i--);
    for (; i >= 0 && !args[i].isBlank(); i--);
    return i == -1;
}
```

This also removes the need for the variable `isGapless`.

With Streams you can use [dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... args) {
    List<String> argsList = Arrays.asList(args);
    Collections.reverse(argsList);
    return argsList.stream()
            .dropWhile(String::isBlank)
            .noneMatch(String::isBlank);
}
```

Note that this approach creates an additional list.

**General recommendation**: I believe you have your reasons to try to make the code shorter. As also others pointed out, making the code shorter often affects readability and that is hardly worth it. I have to admit that the solutions I provided are not the most readable, so think twice before using them in a shared project. On the other hand, if you are the only maintainer and doing some experiments it's totally fine. Good luck with your project.

Comment: tested and works. +1. from java doc's i could not figure out how dropWhile is doing it for unordered list - `returns, if this stream is unordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping a subset of elements that match the given predicate.`  So if I have after reversing  {a, b, " ", d, " ", f }, for this unordered list i am hoping the output will be {a, b, d, f}. But seems i am wrong. Any hints.

Comment: plz don't ask for a SOF post - that will loose the context and can get lengthy for me.

Comment: got it - `Certain stream sources (such as List or arrays) are intrinsically ordered, whereas others (such as HashSet) are not.`

Comment: I've had to look at some of my code after 5 or even 10 years... Even if you're the sole maintainer clarity matters! ;-)

Comment: When reviewing this answer could try to improve names: (a) `isGapLessHierarchy(String... args)` to `hasConsequentHierarchy(Address address)` to communicate domain-knowledge and specific purpose (instead of over-generic vagueness)

Answer (score 8):

As a long-term Java programmer, I know that most of my time will be spent in maintenance.

On that basis I prefer simple code that expresses its purpose clearly to clever, concise, unclear code.

With that context in place here's some basic comments.

```
 String a="a", b="b", c="c", d="d";
```

- It's not the Java way to do multiple declarations together - I'd
  split these.
- They are constants not variables, so they should be "static final" (and UPPERCASE).
- Three of them are not used, so delete them.

  System.out.println(shc.isGapLessHierarchy("a", b, "", "") );
- Why do you mix use of a constant and a literal? As a maintenance
  programmer looking at your code I'm now wondering whether this has
  some significance.

Now to your "isGapLessHierarchy()" method:

- The method has no dependency on an object, so it should be "static"
- Never call anything "args" (other than perhaps the arguments to a main method). Give your method parameters meaningful names. How about "hierarchyElements" in this case?
- (Almost) Never use 'i' and 'j' as indexes. Use something meaningful.
- Going forwards through a list is (IMHO) clearer than going backwards. Your condition can be expressed as "a gap should never be followed by a non-gap", which allows us to go forwards.

Here's my code using your pattern, with some cleanup and adding a more extensive set of tests (I couldn't be bothered with Junit in this case, but you probably should).

```
  public class HierarchyCheck {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] testCases = new String[][]{
      new String[]{"Name", "Street", "City", "County", "State", "Country"},
      new String[]{"Name", "Street", "City", "County", "State", ""},
      new String[]{"Name", "Street", "City", "County", "", "Country"},
      new String[]{"Name", "Street", "", "County", "State", "Country"},
      new String[]{"Name", "", "City", "", "State", "Country"},
      new String[]{"Name", "", "", "", "", ""}
    };

    for (String[] testCase : testCases) {
      System.out.format("%s %s gapLess%n", 
                        Arrays.toString(testCase),
                        isGapLessHierarchy(testCase) ? "is" : "is not");
    }
  }

  private static boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... hierarchyElements) {

    // Find the first gap
    int firstGap = 0;
    for (firstGap = 0; firstGap < hierarchyElements.length; firstGap++) {
      if (isBlank(hierarchyElements[firstGap])) {
        break;
      }
    }

    // Is there a non-gap after the first gap?
    for (int nonGap = firstGap + 1; nonGap < hierarchyElements.length; nonGap++) {
      if (!isBlank(hierarchyElements[nonGap])) {
        // There is, so it's not gapless
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Definitely gapless
    return true;
  }

  // We don't have Java 11 for the String.isBlank() method, so fake it!
  private static boolean isBlank(String string) {
    return (string == null) || (string.trim().length() == 0);
  }
}
```

However, I'd probably have gone for a simpler, arguably cruder approach.

```
  private static boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... hierarchyElements) {

    boolean seenGap = false;

    for (String hierarchyElement : hierarchyElements) {
      if (isBlank(hierarchyElement)) {
        seenGap = true;
      }
      else {
        if (seenGap) { // gap followed by non-gap
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    // Definitely gapless
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: good advice. +1. Thanks

Comment: I would even try to avoid _negation_ whenever possible: `it's not gapless` means "has gaps" and `gap-less` is probably _continuous_. Athough I am neither domain-expert nor native-speaker 

Comment: Fair points @hc_dev but there were limits to how much I could fit in, given that I basically did my review and rewrites in a coffee break.

Answer (score 2):

**What I'd recommend:**
If Gapless, only a single complete iteration of the sequence is required. Otherwise, checks till the first gap found.

```java
    private boolean isGapLessHierarchy(String... args) { //Hierarchy 
        int i=args.length-1;
        while(args[i].isBlank() && i>=0)  //till data is found
            i--;
        for(--i; i>=0; i--)
            if(args[i].isBlank())  //gap found i.e false 
                return false;
        return true; //is necessary
    }
```

**What you did:**
Nested the j-controlled loop in the i-controlled loop.
For every Gapless sequence you pass on, parts of the sequence are checked multiple times.
The last return statement is necessary to get `true` as return from the function.

Comment: Why `i>=0;` above the while loop?

Comment: A mistake while pasting. Sorry. I don't have Java 11 where String.isBlank() was introduced https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank() and hence could not run the program before presenting.

Comment: i got the core logic. Thanks for it. That's wonderful. Tiny things matter for programmer. +1.

Comment: Happy to help. You can accept my answer if it solved your problem. Marc's code is more concise, though.

Comment: Small thing: `return isGapLess` can be reduced to `return true`. `isGapLess` is never modified, which makes it always equal to `true` and is thus not needed.

Comment: @JensV Done. Thanks for pointing out.